# collapsing duplicate rows in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am working on a large data.table, where I am taking lead/lag values. This is an reduced example of my data:

```
> data.table(from = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2012, 2013, 2014),
+            item = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
+            loc = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "other", "others", NA, "NY", "NY", "M"))
    from item    loc
 1: 2012    A   <NA>
 2: 2013    A   <NA>
 3: 2014    A   <NA>
 4: 2012    B   <NA>
 5: 2013    B   <NA>
 6: 2013    B  other
 7: 2013    B others
 8: 2014    C   <NA>
 9: 2012    C     NY
10: 2013    C     NY
11: 2014    C      M
```

Item B has multiple enteries for the same year & item combination, because the `loc` is different. For every `from` & `item` I want them to appear only once. I would like to collapse these cases and have "multiple" in the `loc` column. How can this be done with data.table in R?

desired output:

```
    from item    loc
 1: 2012    A   <NA>
 2: 2013    A   <NA>
 3: 2014    A   <NA>
 4: 2012    B   <NA>
 5: 2013    B   multiple
 8: 2014    C   <NA>
 9: 2012    C     NY
10: 2013    C     NY
11: 2014    C      M
```

Comment: the combination `2012 and A` also does appear 3 times. On Do you mean you only aggregate on `CONSECUTIVES duplicates`?

Comment: that was just an bad example from my side, please see the update question

Comment: Is there a specific reason `2014` `C` is not `"multiple"`?

Comment: yes.. the item can change location between years. But if there are multiple locations assignd to one item & year combinations, there is no way to know which is the correct one, so "multiple" is assigned

Comment: To clarify further, if it is `NA` and `M`, you do not want `"multiple"`. You want to retain `M`, and drop the `NA`? At least, that is what your example shows. I think it makes sense to call that `"multiple"`, but I do not have the full context. Just clarifying.

Comment: Yes exactly. If there was was M and NA I would like to retain M. Good question

Comment: maybe try `DT[, .(loc=if (.N > 1L) 'multiple' else loc[1L]), .(from, item)]`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
aggregate(loc ~ from + item, df, function(x)ifelse(length(x) > 1, "multiple", x), na.action = NULL)
  from item      loc
1 2012    A     <NA>
2 2013    A     <NA>
3 2014    A     <NA>
4 2012    B     <NA>
5 2013    B multiple
6 2012    C       NY
7 2013    C       NY
8 2014    C multiple
```

Comment: is ot possible to change only those loc observations where the from and item combination are the same? Because here also the last observation is changed, which i want to keep as in original

Comment: basically item can change location between years, but no item should have two locations - if an itam has two locations in the same year, melt the locations in "multiple"

Comment: + i wanted to use a data.table, as my original data is very large